# How can I send brainwave sensor values to robotis-op2

Tags: webots

How can I send brainwave sensor values to `robotis-op2`. I have neurosky sensor and I want to send the values of the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Webots controllers are like any normal program, so you should include the library implementing the communicating with the neurosky sensor in your program and use it to interface your controller with the sensor.